# How make responsive images in Ckeditor using Responsive Filemananger

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, responsive-filemanager

I'm using Ckeditor and Responsive filemanager. I want that uploaded images were responsive. But when I upload an image, and see it on the article page, it isn't responsive. Even the image goes beyond `div`. How can I make it responsive?

Comment: "responsive" is a broad term. What do you mean by "responsive image"? Do you expect it to be 100% width (unless the container is too big and resolution would be bad) or what? What have you tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution. When adding image to ckeditor just need in ckeditor property window. Instead of pixels use percent.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHGY3.png)